# WPF TabControl with Overflow Icons

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

I have 7 tabitems in my tabcontrol and the width of the tabcontrol is only 500. Therefore the tabitems are displayed in 3 rows. I want it to be shown in a dropdown at the end of the tabcontrol just like an overflow tabcontrol. How can I create it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look [here on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfTabControl.aspx). I am thinking this will do what you want.  Basically all you have to do is make a control template for your tab control.